# looping through an array of strings and converting to ints

Tags: c#

I have an array of strings, most of which are values "true" or "false" some are not and are to remain as are. 
I wish to loop through the array and change any "true" or "false" to 1' or zero's
I have kind of started it, but am struggling with the syntax

```
string[] data = args.Trim().Split(',');

// Loop over strings
foreach (string s in data)
{
    if(s == "true")
    {
        Convert.ToInt32(s)=1;????
    }
    else if(s == "false")
    {
        ??????
    }
}
```

please can someone offer some guidance

Comment: where do you want to put the converted values ?

Comment: Can you show what is expected output for string `"this,true,is,not,false"`?

Comment: I would expect ["this", "1", "is", "not", "0"]

Comment: Then you want this in the same array? You cannot have both strings and ints in a strongly typed array. You can set the array type to object but then you would need to box / unboxed the types.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps with Linq:

```
string[] data = args.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(s => StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals("true", s.Trim()) ? "1"
               : StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals("false", s.Trim()) ? "0" : s)
    .ToArray();
```

Added the `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` to show how you can ignore the case if desired.

[**Here's**](http://ideone.com/Ifz8BE) a demo with the sample string commented.

```
this,1,is,not,0
```

Answer (score 2):

Write a function like this. You can then copy the "converted data" into a new `List` and return it as an `array`, or whatever.

```
public string[] GetData()
{
   string[] data = args.Trim().Split(',');
    List<string> returnData = new List<string>();
        // Loop over strings
    foreach (string s in data)
    {
        if(s == "true"){
           returnData.Add("1");
        }
        else if(s == "false"){
            returnData.Add("0");
        }
        else
            returnData.Add(s);
    }

    return returnData.ToArray();
 }
```

made a presumption you want an `array` of type `string` as you don't specify.

Other options as it's unclear what your going to do with the two types of data are to parse the values when you get them out, or split them up into two lists.

```
string[] rawDatas = GetData();
foreach(string rawData in rawDatas)
{
    short iRawData;
    if (Int16.TryParse(rawData, out iRawData))
    {
        if (iRawData == 1 || iRawData == 0)
        {
          //Add a bit
          iRawData;
        }
        else
        {
          // add a string
          rawData;
        }
    }
    else
    {
       //add a string
       rawData;
    }
}
```

**OR**

```
public void GetData(out List<string> strings, out List<Int16> shorts)
{
   string[] data = args.Trim().Split(',');
   strings= new List<string>();
   shorts = new List<Int16>();
        // Loop over strings
    foreach (string s in data)
    {
        if(s == "true"){
           shorts.Add(1);
        }
        else if(s == "false"){
            shorts.Add(0);
        }
        else
            returnData.Add(s);
    }
 }
```

**OR**
add to an array of object, though this will need casting back on the other side, which is inefficent (see [boxing and unboxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/yz2be5wk.aspx))

```
public object[] GetData()
{
   string[] data = args.Trim().Split(',');
    List<object> returnData = new List<object>();
        // Loop over strings
    foreach (string s in data)
    {
        if(s == "true"){
           returnData.Add(1);
        }
        else if(s == "false"){
            returnData.Add(0);
        }
        else
            returnData.Add(s);
    }

    return returnData.ToArray();
 }
```

Comment: +1: the only answer that actually conforms to the spec. People should spend more time reading and less time frantically cobbling code together in an effort to make a quick post.

Comment: @AlexG No actually, OP wants `int`s not `"1"` :)

Comment: @AlexG Ha ha, too true!

Comment: @l4v, well he can't?! He can't have ints and strings? unless he wants objects? *some are not and are to remain as are.*

Comment: @I4V as stated above, that is not possible in a strongly-typed array. Liam made the reasonable assumption that a string array was wanted. If this is not the case then the OP should clarify.

Comment: Well ok i think to clarify (forgive my vagueness, im new to coding in general ), the idea is that the resulting list (array) will end up containing a mixture of 1's (Bit), 0's(Bit) and some strings(NVarchar). These are all destin to become parameters for a SQL update, the table is a combination of the Bits and NVarchars.

Comment: you can't have mixture of bits and strings in a table column or a strongly typed language like C#. This is why I'm returning strings above. So your next step is to look at how your going to store your data and then implement the above method accordingly.

Comment: @Liam yes agree with you there. There are 38 columns in the database5 with a string as their data and the rest are Bit. So all i need to do is get the contents of 'data' into a list that will not care if they are 0's, 1's (Bits maybe?) or indeed strings. Thanks

Comment: Ok, modified my code to show how you could deal with this. The other option is to return two arrays.

Comment: Which I've also added.

Comment: Or you could return an array of objects, which I wouldn't really recommend.

Comment: @Liam for clarification i would like to end up with a array that will hold both strings and Bits (0's & 1's). Then with that mixed bag of bits and strings i would like to assign them one by one to an sql parameter eg: seCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Supplier", SqlDbType.Bit)); 
before then actually adding that Bit to the parameter: seCmd.Parameters["@Supplier"].Value = data[1]; 
and then running the commands Stored procedure. the store procedure will take each of those params and run an update to add the relevant    0's, 1's and strings. Hope that helps clarify :)

Comment: Ok, last time. **you cannot have an array that holds bits and strings** C# is strongly typed

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_typing

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28302/discussion-between-moid101-and-liam)

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to do 0 and 1 than

```
   string[] data = args.Trim().Split(',');
   int[] a = new int[data.length];
        // Loop over strings
   int count=0;
    foreach (string s in data)
    {
        if(s == "true"){
           int a[count] = 1;
        }
        else if(s == "false"){
          int a[count]=0;
        }
        else
        {
          a[count] = Convert.ToInt32(s);
         }
      count++;
    }
```

or with linq

```
var intlst = data.
  Select(input => input == "true" ? 1 : 
     (input == "false" ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(input)));
```

Comment: How do you plan to use `a`?

Comment: ... Just edited so no longer valid

Comment: @I4V - just updated with all requirement given by OP

Comment: @TheKingDave -  just updated with all requirement given by OP

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var result = data.Select(input => input == "true" ? 1 : (input == "false")? 0 : -1);
```

Comment: What about not `false` and not `true`? (not my downvote)

Comment: My downvote - does not do what the question asked: *most of which are values "true" or "false" some are not and **are to remain as are*** (admittedly it is quite hard to parse mentally but the code sample backs it up)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by simple for loop:

```
        List<string> newArgs = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= args.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            newArgs.Add(args[i] == "true" ? "1"
                : args[i] == "false" ? "0"
                : args[i]);
        }
```

Or by using linq which will internally use extension object to iterate through the collection.

Answer (score -4):

Well the problem that I can see you running into is holding the variables themselves without creating a new array. When you type the line

```
string[] data = args.Trim().Split(',');
```

you are declaring that the variables within that array are of type string. If you wish to convert them to integers you will need to create a new array of integers or undefined type. I think you are using C# which I believe the code for multiple types in an array is

```
object[]
```

In that case you would do something like

```
object[] data = args.Trim().Split(',');
foreach(string s in data){
    if(s == "true"){
        s = 1;
        Convert.ToInt32(s);
    }
    else if(s == "false"){
        s = 0;
        Convert.ToInt32(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: That won't compile? how can you set `string s = 1`? and what does `Convert.ToInt32(s)` do?

Comment: -1: this won't compile. C# is strongly-typed, it is not possible to assign an int value to a string variable. Also `Convert.ToInt32` is not an in-place operation (it can't be - it is changing types). I would recommend only answering questions in languages that you are familiar with.

Comment: `-1` - You should probably stop answering `C#` questions for a while.